# Como puedo Enviar un Arreglo en el post usando JSON?

Tags: c#, json, razor

Tengo una funcion en ajax que crea un arreglo de un objeto y lo manda a la PageModel mediante un post.

```
function guardarOrden(data) {
        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/EntradasAlmacen/NuevaEntrada?handler=SaveOrder",

            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        });
    }

    $("#guardarOrden").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var ordenArr = [];
        ordenArr.length = 0;

        $.each($("#tblProductos tbody tr"), function () {
            alert($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html());

            ordenArr.push({
                IdProducto: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                DescProducto: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                Cantidad: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()
            });
        });


        var data = JSON.stringify({
            order: ordenArr
        });

        $.when(guardarOrden(data)).then(function (response) {
            alert(response);
            console.log("Respuesta:"+response);
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

Pero cuando llama al método el valor siempre llega nulo al PageModel, que puede estar fallando.

Esta es la funcion del pagemodel

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveOrderAsync(Producto[] order)
    {
    }
```

Comment: tengo una duda, tu llamas en el ajax a `SaveOrder` pero tu método se llama `OnPostSaveOrderAsync`, eso esta bien? Otra cosa, prueba utilizar una lista en vez de arreglo, `OnPostSaveOrderAsync(List<Producto> order)`

Comment: Si es Correcto Razor no toma en en cuenta OnPost y Async, el método si se ejecuta correctamente solo que orden es null siempre, voy a revisar que pasa con el cambio de la lista. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás te falte colocar [WebMethod] y cambiar order por data:

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public async  Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveOrderAsync(Producto[] data)
{
}
```

Comment: Lo del webMethod estas en lo correcto, lo de data no importa.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines el `dataType: 'json'` no es necesario realizar el `JSON.stringify`

[Web API With AJAX: Understanding POST Request in Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-understand-post-request-in-web-api/)

como observaras en el ejemplo se envia un objeto directamente

```
 var person = new Object();
 person.name = $('#name').val();
 person.surname = $('#surname').val();

 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:3413/api/person',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: person,
     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log('Error in Operation');
     }
 });
```

intente primero enviando una orden simple para ver si resuelve, luego envia el array que tambien podrias definir como `List<Producto>`

Sino quieres usar el `Object` podrias usar la notacion json

```
 var person = {
  name: $('#name').val(),
  surname: $('#surname').val()
 };
```

pero no le apliques el stringify

---

Por otro lado observo que la url dice:

```
url: "/EntradasAlmacen/NuevaEntrada?handler=SaveOrder",
```

pero en la api el nombre no coincide `OnPostSaveOrderAsync`

Entonces el action se llama `NuevaEntrada` o `OnPostSaveOrderAsync` ? intenta invocar al api usando algun aplicacion como ser `Postman`

Esto teniendo en cuenta que el nombre del controller: `EntradasAlmacen` sea correcto

Comment: Se que suena extraño que se llame `OnPostSaveOrderAsync` y yo solo la llame como `SaveOrder`, pero si funciona correctamente, el método hace mas cosas y todas las hace bien pero el parametro que es el objeto json siempre es nulo aun y cuando mandas un simple texto